# Trouble with Request URLs sent by QueryPanel.js

Tags: geoserver, geoext, query

I use the GeoExt QueryPanel, which I got working so far. I configured an osgeo proxy on my Apache Server, I use the override-ext-ajax.js and have the `OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";` class configured. My problem is the following: When the [QueryPanel.js](http://projects.opengeo.org/suite/browser/trunk/recipes/resources/extras/QueryPanel.js?rev=1708) sends requests to geoserver, it uses wrong URLs which I figured must be related to the QueryPanel.js file. The sent request URLs look like this:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcgibin%2Fproxy.cgi%2Fwfs%3F
VERSION%3D1.1.0%26REQUEST%3DDescribeFeatureType%26TYPENAME%3Dcases%26query%3D
```

The request is sent via the proxy.cgi twice. The request URL should rather look like this, going passed geoserver´s WFS:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fgeoserver%2Fwfs%3F
VERSION%3D1.1.0%26REQUEST%3DDescribeFeatureType%26TYPENAME%3Dcases%26query%3D
```

When using firebug, I can temporarily change the URLs and make the queries work! When replacing line 182

```
url: Ext.urlAppend(protocol.url, Ext.urlEncode({
```

with

`url: Ext.urlAppend("http://localhost/geoserver/wfs", Ext.urlEncode({,`

the describeFeatureType requests are sent the right way, but attribute queries are still using the wrong URL (`localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi/wfs` instead of `localhost/geoserver/wfs`). I can´t find the responsible line for the query URLs and I´m also not really sure what to replace, since I´m quite new to JS & GeoExt. If it´s not possible to fix my problem that way, can you see another method to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the source of the problem - think it was a setting that I made when having difficulties configuring a WFS. In GeoServer Globale settings, I set the Proxy Base URL to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=`, which I changed to `http://localhost/geoserver`
now and all works fine...

Sorry for any confusion!